# Importing MaxMind GeoLite2 City

Tags: php, api, curl, maxmind

I'm trying to download the binaries for MaxMind GeoLite2 City API on my Ubuntu Server so that I can use it. I am using curl to download http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLite2-City.mmdb.gz The problem arises when I try to download the binaries. I get all this messy text with like PUTTY and odd unicode characters. Finally it doesn't even download the file. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

By default, curl outputs to stdout. In order to download to a local file with the same name, use the `-O` option, e.g.:

```
curl -O http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLite2-City.mmdb.gz
```

Permalinks for GeoLite2 City

Below are permalinks that you can use to download the database.

Remember to replace YOUR_LICENSE_KEY.

## Database URL

https://download.maxmind.com/app/geoip_download?edition_id=GeoLite2-City&license_key=YOUR_LICENSE_KEY&suffix=tar.gz

## Database URL CSV Format

https://download.maxmind.com/app/geoip_download?edition_id=GeoLite2-City-CSV&license_key=YOUR_LICENSE_KEY&suffix=zip

## SHA256 URL

https://download.maxmind.com/app/geoip_download?edition_id=GeoLite2-City&license_key=YOUR_LICENSE_KEY&suffix=tar.gz.sha256

## SHA256 URL CSV Format

https://download.maxmind.com/app/geoip_download?edition_id=GeoLite2-City-CSV&license_key=YOUR_LICENSE_KEY&suffix=zip.sha256